# Use data from Gridview 1 to populate Gridview 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, foreach

This may not even be possible but I have a gridivew that for example data is :

[image]

I want to then populate a second gridview that shows item and orders of that item like so:

[image]

Is this even possible? Thought about doing a FOREACH loop like this but don't know how I would group by item # then do a i++ for each order of that item?

```
 DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable();

    // Items for the product Gridview
    foreach (GridViewRow row in ordersGridView.Rows)
    {
        var products = from orderRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       group orderRow["orderNo"] by orderRow["itemNo"] into grp
                       select new { product = grp.Key, orders = grp.Count() };

        dt.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var prod in products)
        {
            DataRow r = dtProducts.NewRow();
            r["PRODUCTS"] = prod.product;
            r["ORDERS"] = prod.orders;
            dtProducts.Rows.Add(r);
        }
    }

    productGridView.DataSource = dtProducts;
    productGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that first table of yours has at least two fields: ORDERID and ITEM:

First, the  query will give you an enumerable of items with two fields - product and the count of orders. Then, should you want that as DataTable, you can just loop over the query result.

```
var products = from orderRow in dtOrders.AsEnumerable()
    group orderRow["ORDERID"] by orderRow["ITEM"] into grp
    select new { product = grp.Key, orders = grp.Count() };

dtProducts.Rows.Clear();
foreach (var prod in products)
{
    DataRow r = dtProducts.NewRow();
    r["PRODUCTS"] = prod.product;
    r["ORDERS"] = prod.orders;
    dtProducts.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

I think it's possible to combine those two steps, but this should get you started at least :)

Comment: I updated my code above.. that is what I'm using and it shows nothing in the dtProducts Gridview when I run it?

Comment: No need to put that thing inside that foreach loop. It will give you entire list, 1 object per each product, containing product name and count of orders. That DataGridView is based on a table, right? The basis for that first table in your question. Answer assumed that this table in your code is named dtOrders. And that it has columns "ORDERID" (the one that holds 1, 2, 3..) and a column named "ITEM", that holds "CAR1", "HAMMER", etc. If the table name or column names are different, replace these names in my answer. Then see if the dtProducts table gets populated, as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to do group by two different fields or a count of two different fields based off that one item?

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work and works great... thanks everyone :

```
 var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     group row["orderNo"] by row["itemNo"] into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         itemNum = grp.Key,
                         orders = grp.Count()
                     };
        foreach (var t in result)
        {
            dtProducts.Rows.Add(t.itemNum, t.orders, "", "");
        }
```